# Probability for sampling at least one member of a set from a larger set

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's assume the following:

```
Population size: N
Individuals with a particular feature: x% of N
Sample size: y% of N
```

What's the chance that we get at least one individual with that particular feature in our sample based on `N`, `x`, `y`? Sampling is done without replacement.

(`N` - population size, `x` - percent of individuals with the particular feature, `y` - sampling percent)

---

Here's an example:

```
Population size: 10
Individuals with a particular feature: 30% of 10 = 3
Sample size: 30% of 10 = 3
```

The chance of picking at least one individual with that particular feature is `70.83%`.

Comment: Is sampling done with replacement or without?

Comment: Without replacement. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert the percentages of the population to integers (as in your example):

Say there are $c=N\cdot\frac{x}{100}$ individuals in the population with the characteristic; and the sample size is $k=N\cdot \frac{y}{100}$.

Then the probability of at least one person having the characteristic would be
$$1-\frac{\binom{N-c}{k}}{\binom{N}{k}}$$

The numerator of the fraction in the preceding expression comes from choosing $k$ people without the characteristic.

If you can't get exact numbers, but if the sample is quite small compared to the population (i.e., $y$ is a very small percentage), then sampling without replacement may be a reasonable approximation to sampling with replacement.  Then the probability would be approximately equal to
$$1-\left(1-\frac{x}{100}\right)^{\frac{yN}{100}}$$